# Function doesn't call after fetch data

Tags: swift, multithreading

I implemented a method which fetch the data but the method which update the layput doesn't call.
Method the update UI in main thread DispatchQueue.main.async .

```
func fetchData() {
    self.getCars(completionHandler: { status in
                        if status {
                            self.carsDetails(completionHandler: { (array) in
                                    self.updateLayout(array)
                                }
                            }) { (error) in
                                self.showErrorMessage(error)
                            }                                
                        } else {
                            self.showErrorMessage(error)
                        }
    }) { (error) in
        self.showErrorMessage(error)
    }
}
```

The method updateLayout doesn't call.
I have to update the information in  many situations.

Comment: Show the bodies of `getCars` and `carsDetails ` methods. One of them is not calling the completion handler.

Comment: @mag_zbc  I fixed the problem; in "carsDetails" I started a listener and send status ok when it was connected not when it start send information